# Re-create sql log using detach

Tags: sql-server

OK, before I start, I know you're not supposed to do this...

I have inherited a SQL Server instance (2008 R2 SP2 x64) which has a DB with a very large transaction log (full mode, with no tlog backups), and the log is in a compressed folder (don't ask). I need to sort this out and was thinking my best approach would be to detach the database (no reason why it shouldn't checkpoint) and re-attach the mdf ignoring the ldf so a new one is created in a proper folder structure. I can then implement a decent backup strategy.

I really don't want to backup this tlog as it's huge, and in a compressed folder so who knows how big it really is. Another option was to simply truncate the tlog but that's deprecated... Maybe backup the tlog to /dev/null (whatever the windows equiv is)?

Obviously I'd do a full backup before anything - these occur daily anyway.

I guess what I'm asking is, what is the safest approach here?

EDIT: actually, I've just thought - if I'm doing daily full backups, would the tlog not be useless immediately after the BU anyway?

Comment: You can also change the recovery model to simple and shrink the log to a reasonable size. You can switch back to full recovery at a later moment

Comment: @spaghettidba That's not a bad idea actually, did't think about it from that POV.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking there are two questions here? How do I shrink my ldf file and how do I move my ldf? Because it looks like you want to do both at once, while just shrinking then moving seems like an easier solution.

Comment: @Reaces not exactly, I can do both these things - I want advice on the safest approach in this situation. There's the added complexity of a compressed folder too.

Comment: since the recovery model is FULL, take couple of log backups (if you dont want just delete them .. since you have a FULL backup). Then use `dbcc shrinkfile` to shrink the file to a sensible value (make sure that you dont shrink it too low since it will autogrow).

Comment: You can also backup to `NUL`. Should be even faster than backing up to a real device. However I don't see it particularly different from changing the recovery model.

Comment: @Kin I was trying to avoid backing up the tlog - I think the approach spaghettidba has suggested (switch to simple mode and shrink the log) is probably my best bet so far.

Comment: Something doesn't add up here - you're trying to avoid backing up the log, why? You're in full recovery model, right? Why don't you want to back up the log? You know that backing up the log does NOT mean making a copy of the large LDF file, right?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yeah, I don't need the contents of the log - it's never been backed up (only full backups). So you're saying if I do a tlog backup it won't be around the same size as the ldf? Will it only "backup" the changes since the last full BU? FYI - the ldf is 27GB and the mdf is 1.2GB

Comment: @dwjv, the backup of the log will not be the same size as the actual ldf.  Though it you've never backed it up, it will still be pretty large.  Even so, what Kin and Aaron are suggesting is safer because it retains your log chain.  If it were me and I was moving the DB, I'd put it in single user mode so no more changes can be made, take a tlog backup and shrink as Kin suggested, then do another full backup.  You can then restore that full backup wherever you want WITH RECOVERY knowing you have all your data, with a smaller log file, maintaining all your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, please [do not detach your database and move the log file](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups). Follow the advice from Kin, spaghettidba, and others, but take a full backup first (you'll need to adjust `db` to your database name, and `db_log` and `db.ldf` to the log file logical and physical names, according to `sp_helpfile`):

```
BACKUP DATABASE db TO DISK = 'backup location' WITH INIT;

-- set it to single user
ALTER DATABASE db SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

-- set the recovery mode to simple
ALTER DATABASE db SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;

-- run checkpoint twice
CHECKPOINT;
CHECKPOINT;

-- shrink the log file to something more reasonable (please not 1 MB):
DBCC SHRINKFILE(db_log, 1024); -- 1 GB

-- take the database offline
ALTER DATABASE db SET OFFLINE;

-- tell the system catalogs that you're moving the file
ALTER DATABASE db MODIFY FILE 
  (NAME = db_log, FILENAME = 'x:\other_drive\db.ldf');
```

Stop here. This should tell you:

> The file "db_log" has been modified in the system catalog. The new path will be used the next time the database is started.

So, move the LDF file (which should now be about 1 GB) to `x:\other_drive\` and then bring the database back online and multi-user:

```
ALTER DATABASE db SET ONLINE;
ALTER DATABASE db SET MULTI_USER;
```

(To be honest, I'd feel safer restoring the backup `WITH MOVE`; any time you start moving files around, you're opening yourself up to loss/corruption. But as long as you took your full backup right before you started this process, that should protect you.)

Now, leave the thing in simple recovery if you don't care about transaction logs and don't care to learn why they're important. But I really, really, really strongly recommend you read this post in full:

- [Why Does the Transaction Log Keep Growing or Run Out of Space?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29829/1186)

Try to understand your employer's tolerance for data loss, because I can assure you that most businesses cannot afford to be laissez-faire about this, and 24 hours of loss is absolutely not acceptable. If this is true in your workplace, then set the database back to full recovery, and immediately take a full+log backup to start the log backup chain:

```
ALTER DATABASE db SET RECOVERY FULL;

BACKUP DATABASE db TO DISK = N'backup_location\db_full.bak';
GO
BACKUP LOG db TO DISK = N'backup_location\db_init.trn';
```

Then create some kind of job that will take regular log backups throughout the day. Every hour might not be enough; again, make sure the owners of the data understand the trade-offs involved with not backing up the log often enough. I doubt that even an hour of data loss will be acceptable to them. And no, the .trn files will rarely be as large as the LDF itself; this will only happen in extreme scenarios where the log file blew up because of activity that happened since the last log backup.

Also, don't let SQL Server anywhere near compressed drives. Disk space is cheap; have them invest in enough space to adequately store your data and copies related to fault tolerance.